# Use .htaccess to simplify URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to turn a URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/media/video/vimeo/123456
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/media/video?player=vimeo&vid=123456
```

The domain name stay the same, only the request uri needs to be rewritten. Here is what I have in .htaccess, but no luck so far.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/media/video/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /media/video?player=$1&vid=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/` in front of media on the condition in the RewriteRule. It won't match with that there in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^media/video/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /media/video?player=$1&vid=$2 [L]
```